# Reference request: Kawasaki dynamics for Ising model

Tags: particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, ising-model, spin-models

I want to learn more about Glauber and Kawasaki dynamics which, by my understanding, are used to model lattice spin systems for the pre-equilibrium Ising model.

There seems to be quite a few references explaining Glauber dynamics at a simple level (e.g. wikipedia) but I haven't been able to find course notes or any similar introductory reference for Kawasaki dynamics.

In particular I'm looking for an explicit statement of the dynamics (as done for Glauber, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glauber_dynamics#The_algorithm)), as well as a derivation of the Markov generator, some intuition, and other basic theoretical properties.

Comment: I don't have a specific reference to give you. However, if you understand how the usual Glauber or Metropolis dynamics work, then Kawasaki is just a slight variant. For instance, in the Metropolis version, you would select 2 spins at random, compute the change of energy $\Delta E$ resulting from an exchange of these two spins, and interchange them either if $\Delta E\leq 0$ or with probability $e^{-\beta\Delta E}$ if $\Delta E > 0$. (Of course, if the two spins take the same value, you can just skip the computation as the move would not change anything.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik Is the following true?: Glauber dynamics selects a random site and switches the spin with probability $e^{-\beta \Delta E}$ where $\Delta E$ is the change in energy if the spin were switched. On the other hand, Kawasaki dynamics selects a random pair of adjacent sites and swaps their spins with the same probability except that $\Delta E$ is the change in energy if the two spins were swapped.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. (Although it is not required that the 2 spins be neighbors; this might be natural if you are interested in the dynamics itself, but it slows down the relaxation if you're only interested in the properties of the stationary distribution, *i.e*., the corresponding fixed-magnetization Gibbs state.)

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thanks! I appreciate your help. Is "symmetric simple exclusion process" another name for the Kawasaki dynamics? E.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/030441499190034A

Comment: No. The simple exclusion process is simpler: there is no energy involved (thus no temperature), the only constraint is that two particles cannot simultaneously occupy the same site. Usually, people consider a drift, however, so that particles move preferentially in some direction (resulting in a macroscopic current). In the symmetric case (*i.e.*, with no drift), the dynamics would be the same as the Kawasaki dynamics for an Ising model at infinite temperature (since you can then ignore the energy).

Comment: Looking at the paper you mention, I see that you are OK with the mathematical physics/probability theory literature. In that case there are many papers on this topic, for instance [this one](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.533193) (chosen almost at random).

Comment: Other papers on related topics: [this one](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.533192), [this one](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPB_2002__38_4_385_0/), [this one](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-156/issue-2/Spectral-gap-and-logarithmic-Sobolev-inequality-for-Kawasaki-and-Glauber/cmp/1104253633.full), etc. As I said, there are many. I was under the impression that you were interested in the algorithmic/simulation aspects more than the mathematical ones, which is why I did not mention any before...

Comment: @YvanVelenik Thank you for the references, I will have to spend some more time on those but for now, I'm confused again. It seems from these papers that mixing times is the main quantity of interest when studying these dynamics? I thought that the reverse of mixing (phase separation) occurs.

Comment: @YvanVelenik I'm new to this area, and got interested in G-K dynamics because I found that the hydrodynamic limit of the G-K interface gives mean curvature flow (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.10182.pdf). Specifically I was interested in seeking an analogous result on a general graphs

Comment: The mixing time is a measure of the time to equilibrium. It is not related to the issue of phase separation (well, of course phase separation has an impact on the time to equilibrium, but it's conceptually unrealated). You are right that phase separation occurs under the fixed-magnetization Gibbs measure (provided that the fixed magnetization lies strictly between $m^*$ and $-m^*$, where $m^*$ is the spontaneous magnetization).

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DljO94GXsKc) is what you see under the Kawasaki dynamics in the Ising model...

Comment: And [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.533180) (or [the arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911106)) is a review about what was known about the fixed-magnetization Gibbs measure in 2000 (but there has not been much progress in this area since then). I have never seen results about Kawasaki dynamics on general graphs, although it seems conceivable that methods extend if your graph is not too wild. Even equilibrium properties have not been studied on general graphs.

Comment: @YvanVelenik wow thanks for all of the info. I'm starting to get a little lost (not much background in physics). Is 'magnetization' the ambient potential field? When you say "conceivable that methods extend" to general graphs, do you refer to mixing time results? And/or properties of the equilibrium? Sorry to continue the conversation in comments. If you put down a stackexchange answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: I have the Liggett text but don't know enough to see which chapter G-K dynamics are in... and it seems to use different terminology. Which chapter would you say is most relevant? https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b138374

Comment: If I remember correctly, Liggett only discusses Glauber dynamics (in his chapter on the Ising model). The magnetization (density) of an Ising system defined on a finite graph with vertex set $V$ is the random variable $m_V = \frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{i\in V} \sigma_i$; one often also uses the same terminology for its expectation value under the Gibbs measure on $V$.

Comment: When I say "conceivable that methods extend", I am not referring to any particular results. The rougher the results, the more likely they will extend to a general class of graph. However, note that, for Kawasaki dynamics, the relevant dynamics is the motion of interfaces (including for rough properties such as the mixing time). This is usually very hard, and little is known. In particular, it seems likely that results proved on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ in this case can only be easily pushed to other regular lattices.

Comment: I haven't given an answer to your question, because I am not an expert on these dynamical aspects (having never worked on that), so it seemed to be better to "answer" in comments. Maybe somebody more knowledgeable will come up :) .